# How does one properly use the Unix exec C(++)-command?

Tags: c++, unix, multiprocessing

Specifically, I need to call a version of exec that maintains the current working directory and sends standard out to the same terminal as the program calling exec. I also have a vector of string arguments I need to pass somehow, and I'm wondering how I would go about doing all of this. I've been told that all of this is possible exclusively with **fork and exec**, and given the terrible lack of documentation on the google, I've been unable to get the exec part working.

What exec method am I looking for that can accomplish this, and how do I call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a vector of strings then you need to convert it to an array of `char*` and call [execvp](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execv.htm)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    vector<string> args;
    args.push_back("Hello");
    args.push_back("World");

    char **argv = new char*[args.size() + 2];
    argv[0] = "echo";
    argv[args.size() + 1] = NULL;
    for(unsigned int c=0; c<args.size(); c++)
        argv[c+1] = (char*)args[c].c_str();

    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
        return 1;

    case 0:
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        // execvp only returns on error
        perror("execvp");
        return 1;

    default:
        wait(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to put a NULL at the end of that argv!

Comment: Don't forget to call c_str().

Comment: Thanks, the code I posted was filled while I hammered out a complete working example.

Comment: Use a vector<char const*> instead of new[] here, and do that after forking.

Comment: I feel like there's a good stl way to do the vector -> char *[] conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [execv() or execvp()](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need google to find this out, you should have the `man` command available so you can `man fork` and `man exec` (or maybe `man 2 fork` and `man 3 exec`) to find out about how the parameters to these system and library functions should be formed.

In Debian and Ubuntu, these man pages are in the `manpages-dev` package which can be installed using synaptic or with:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-dev
```