# How to use exec() to execute commands in C++ and Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

For an assignment, I am to write a program that will work as a command line interpreter, accepting any command, creating a new process with `fork()`, and using the child process to execute the command with `exec()`. The problem is I don't know how to use the `exec()` family of commands, and searching online has proven to be of little help. I am working in C++ on a Linux server at my school.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769734/what-are-the-different-versions-of-exec-used-for-in-c) post, I think I want `execlp()`, but I am really not sure, so please correct me if I'm wrong. When I try this:

```
string s = "/bin/" + command;
execlp(s, command, NULL);
```

just to see if it works with a simple command and no arguments, like `ls`, I cannot even get it to compile, receiving this error:

```
shell.cpp:52: error: cannot convert âstd::stringâ to âconst char*â for argument â1â to âint execlp(const char*, const char*, ...)â
```

when attempting to pass arguments as strings. Annoyingly, our textbook does the exact same thing with string literals, and works successfully, with the statement `execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);`.

Clearly, I don't know how the function is meant to be used, so what I am asking is can someone offer advice or provide a resource as to which `exec()` I should use and how I can use it for this purpose?

Comment: Maybe reading a proper C++ book and learn about types is a good start

Comment: `execlp(s, command.c_str(), NULL);` should fix the compilation error, manpages contain all information about `exec` family.

Comment: The man page explains it.  See http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv

Comment: this answer may  be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739184/how-does-one-properly-use-the-unix-exec-c-command

Comment: Innot Kauker and wallyk, thank you for your responses, they are helpful. texasbruce, I did accidentally cut out the part I had about how changing them to cstrings produces errors requesting a different type for the second argument. However, changing them to cstrings again suddenly produces no compilation error. I can only think I did not transfer the files to the server at some point causing that confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ `string` and `char*` (so called C-string because that's how strings are represented in C) are 2 different types.

As a quick fix (assuming `command` is also a `string`), do this:

```
string s = "/bin/" + command;
execlp(s.c_str(), command.c_str(), NULL);
```

But in the long run, you'll have to learn about strings and how to use them properly.